# Editing XML files

Tags: batch-file, automation, macros, editing, xml

I have some XML files and I need to edit them automatically.

For example

```
<Content>
<Texts>
<Text id="1">
<en value="blaabla" />
</Text>
<Text id="2">
<en value="blablablablal" />
</Text>
</Texts>
</Content>
```

I need to copy "en value" lines and add these lines to their under line but with one change.

So when processing done, result should be that:

```
<Content>
<Texts>
<Text id="1">
<en value="blablabla" />
<fr value="blablabla" />
</Text>
<Text id="2">
<en value="blablablablal" />
<fr value="blablablablal" />
</Text>
</Texts>
</Content>
```

Comment: This can be accomplished using C# .NET, and many other scripting languages.  What were you wanting to do it in?  Makes it so much easier if we can know what you want to use, so we can tailor the answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this XSLT to transform your XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                version="1.0">    
   <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="en[@value]">
        <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
        <fr value="{@value}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed '/<en /p' data.txt | awk '/<en /{if(x++%2)sub(/<en /, "<fr ")}1'
<Content>
<Texts>
<Text id="1">
<en value="blaabla" />
<fr value="blaabla" />
</Text>
<Text id="2">
<en value="blablablablal" />
<fr value="blablablablal" />
```

- using `sed` to duplicate line which contains `<en`
- using `awk` to change the odd `<en` to `<fr`

**WARNING:** `<en ... />` must be one line.