# Batch file commands/handling

Tags: xml, batch-file

I need to perform the following:

- I have a folder of .xml files with text in them
- I need to search for particular xml pairs and pull their values
- I need to iterate through all the .xml files in that folder and output the results to a single file with just the values I need.

How would I go about doing that with a .bat file. I have some notion of working with .bat files but never something this intricate.

Comment: Suggest you consider using [tag:powershell], instead.  It has lots of support for XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps if you show us the general format of your .xml files and the particular pairs you want, we could show you a Batch file that do what you want. A Batch file is written to process files in a particular fixed way, so there are NOT "generic" Batch solutions on other format files, unless the other format is inflexible.

Below there are three examples of .xml file processing with a Batch file:

[Editing XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772125/editing-xml-files/8782927#8782927)

[A batch file to extract the value of a specific XML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217765/a-batch-file-to-extract-the-value-of-a-specific-xml-tag/8220420#8220420)

[How to loop through xml values in a batch cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9912535/how-to-loop-through-xml-values-in-a-batch-cmd/9915014#9915014)

The following Batch file is an example that achieve what you want, assuming that the "xml pairs" you want is the same as the second example above:

```
@echo off
rem I have a folder of .xml files with text in them
cd "C:\Documents and Settings\My Name\The Folder"
rem I need to iterate through all the .xml files in that folder and output the results to a single file with just the values I need. 
(for %%a in (*.xml) do (
   call :check_lines < "%%a"
)) > "The Single File.txt"
exit /b


rem I need to search for particular xml pairs and pull their values 
rem Seek for the start of Data tag
:check_lines
   set /P line=
if not "%line%" == "<DATA>" goto check_lines

rem Copy until the end of Data tag
set /P line=
:put_lines
    if "%line%" == "</DATA>" goto end_lines
    set /P line=%line% 
goto put_lines
:end_lines
echo/
exit /B
```